# Araya 27 1 1/4 rim and tire, max pressure

Tags: tire-pressure

I've just bought new tire (deli tires 145) for my old vintage ARAYA rim (27 1 1/4). Tire is the same size but I don't know which max pressure I can put in them, tire says min 73 PSI.

Comment: Check the tire carefully for labeling.  But generally a tire of that dimension will be designed to run at 90-110 psi.

Comment: On the tire minimum pressure is 73psi and max 90 psi

Comment: I am afraid about my rim,will it stay such pressure(75-80psi)?

Comment: What do you mean by "old vintage"?  If it's from the 70s or later, and it's not been badly worn down by the brake pads, it should easily handle the pressure.

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry about damage to the rim from air pressure in the tire if you inflate the tire to the recommended inflation range.

To say it a different way:

If you inflate your tire somewhere between 73 and 90 psi as labeled on the tire your rim will be fine. The pressure won't damage your rim. The steel or aluminum the rim is made of is much stronger than the material the tire is made of - assuming the rim is not damaged (extensive corrosion etc.)